# Failed virtualbox install prevents my system from starting up properly

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 with kernel 3.3rc6. I tried to install Virtualbox 4.1.8 with the AMD64 .deb package off the virtualbox site. On install I got a kernel panic saying "unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff...".

When I reboot into Ubuntu now, just after it boots up, it starts to run unattended upgrades and I again get:

```
* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
unable to handle kernel paging request at ffff...
...etc
```

I booted up okay on recovery mode, but when I shut down the system it gets stuck on:

```
* Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules
```

and I have to manually power down.

If I try `sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.1`, it similarly gets stuck while stopping the virtualbox kernel modules.

At the moment I'd be happy just removing the problematic install so my system boots up okay. I don't really need virtualbox right now, but I do need a working system. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to sort this out very crudely. I renamed `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv` to `vboxdrv.bak` so that the Virtualbox kernel module service would not start (and hence not get stuck while stopping.)

I then rebooted and did a `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox-4.1`, which worked fine.

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this, and I'll be happy if someone suggests that, but I'm glad this worked for me as I urgently needed my PC up and running.

*EDIT: The problem appeared to be due to the kernel upgrade - I tried 3.3rc6 with 11.10, and 3.3rc7 with 12.04 and both caused the problems I described with Virtualbox and VMWare.*

*However Virtualbox works just fine on stable kernel versions  - I'm currently on 3.2.0-18 on Ubuntu 12.04 (I have not tried VMWare but I assume the problem with that will be solved too)*